# Get a Class Nested inside multiple Div Tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, arcgis, esri

I am trying to get a class called .layerTile, however it is nested inside multiple div tags. The parent div id is mapDiv.

The end game is to apply a CSS filter like grayscale to the class.  Otherwise other layers in the parent div tag will also render with the grayscale filter applied which is not my intention.

I'm using `var el = document.querySelector(".layerTile");`  which is returning a null value when I pass the variable into Console.log.

If I replace the nested class with the parent `var el = document.querySelector(".layerTile");` then I can apply my filters but it applies to every child element inside the Div, like the zoom buttons and the watermark in the lower right corner...!

[CSS Map Tile Filtering](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46430376/CSS%20Filters.html)

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erodenberg/bwaf5ut4/) of my code.  Line 99 in the HTML is where I'm struggling....the class is call layerTile.  If you open Chrome Developer tools or Firebug the layerTile class will be nested deep inside the mapDiv tag found in the article  section of the app.

Comment: Would you be able to post some example code so we can help debug?

Comment: is that class really called `.layerTile`? If so rename the class to `layerTile` then the class selector ( `.`)  will work properly.

Comment: Here is a JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/erodenberg/bwaf5ut4/ of my code. Line 99 in the HTML is where I'm struggling....the class is called layerTile. If you open Chrome Developer tools or Firebug the layerTile class will be nested deep inside the mapDiv tag found in the article section of the app.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. `document.querySelector(".layerTile");` returns the first element with the `layerTile` class and works fine in the Chrome dev console; `document.getElementsByClassName("layerTile");` returns the array-like set of all elements with the `layerTile` class and also works fine in the Chrome dev console.

Comment: @StephenThomas, Thanks for taking a look.  The problem is if I apply a filter effect nothing happens and in my Console I'm am checking to see what my variable el = and it is coming up as null.  I too can see layerTile if I use getElementsByClassName but it is coming back as an array.  I suppose I can loop through the list and apply my filter against each item in the array.  I'd prefer to apply the filter against the class and be done though.